# Is it possible to use xmlstarlet without installing in UNIX?

Tags: unix, installation, xmlstarlet

I need to use the functionalities of XMLStarlet but I dont have permissions to install XMLStarlet. Is it possible to use xmlstarlet without installing in UNIX?

Comment: Download. Configure. Compile. Run.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart How to do that ?